# Nested mysql query for customer and customer_contact table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have 2 tables **customer** and **customer_contact**

Here **customer** has basic information such as 
`id (primary key), name, lastname, gender, dob, username, email, phone` and 
**customer_contact** *has address details of customer* such as `id (primary key), customer_id (foreign key for customer id), name, phone, address, locality, pincode, state, city`

Now customer can have multiple address in customer_contact table which I want to fetch in single query with all his basic information as well, below is query

```
SELECT customer.name, customer.lastname, customer.gender, customer.dob, 
customer.username, customer.email, customer.phone 
    FROM customer, (SELECT id as contact_address_id, 
        name as contact_name, 
        phone as contact_phone, 
        address as contact_address, 
        locality as contact_locality, 
        pincode as contact_pincode, 
        state as contact_state, 
        city as contact_city 
        FROM customer_contact 
        GROUP BY customer_id) customer_contact 
    WHERE customer_contact.customer_id=customer.id AND customer.id='$custId'
```

The above query is giving me "Unknown column 'customer_contact.customer_id' in 'where clause'"

Please do suggest what's going wrong here or if any other better way to write sql query where I get basic information from one table as well as multiple contact details from another table..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -

```
SELECT customer.name, customer.lastname, customer.gender, customer.dob, 
customer.username, customer.email, customer.phone,customer_contact.* FROM customer join 
(SELECT distinct id as customer_id, 
        name as contact_name, 
        phone as contact_phone, 
        address as contact_address, 
        locality as contact_locality, 
        pincode as contact_pincode, 
        state as contact_state, 
        city as contact_city 
        FROM customer_contact 
       ) customer_contact 
    on customer_contact.customer_id=customer.id AND customer.id='$custId'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your updates, I tried it but not getting results from customer_contact table

Comment: @David, because you didn't select anything from customer_contact table, I've edited a bit you can check there

Comment: yes I have made necessary changes but still not getting data from customer_contact table. I guess some $custId variable prob, let me try that..

Comment: @David, then please provide your sample data

Comment: thanks a lot, I got the output.. your query helped a lot